# How do I find out who kept a build forever?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have list of builds that were kept forever, but I can't seem to find who kept these builds. Is there a way of finding that out using the API or through the cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Jenkins does not record this information.